# Why does `a<b<c` work in Python?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

The title says it all. For example `1<2<3` returns `True` and `2<3<1` returns `False`.

It's great that it works, but I can't explain *why* it works... I can't find anything about it in the documentation. It's always: `expression boolean_operator expression`, not two boolean operators). Also: `a<b` returns a boolean, and `boolean boolean_operator expression` does not explain the behaviour.

I'm sure the explanation is (almost) obvious, but I seem to miss it.

Comment: Python resolves `a<b<c` to `a<b and b<c`

Comment: It also will resolve with any two comparison operators, which means `0 < 2 in range(3)` should totally return `True`, no matter how inane that would look in English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as operator chaining.  Documentation is available at:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

And, if you really like formal definitions:

> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`, `op2`, ..., `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for  to the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

Your multiple operators all have the same precedence, so now it is going to work through them serially. `1<2<3` goes to `1<2` which is T, then `2<3` is T. `2<3<1` has two parts, `2<3` is T, but `3<1` is F so the entire expression evaluates to F.

Answer (score 1):

Compare operators can be chained, according to the language reference

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in